# does importing and not using reduces the performance nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, npm, optimization, backend

does...

1. importing the npm package and not using it reduces the performance?
2. importing npm package and using a few functionalities reduces the performance?

e.g. the dim one are not used but imported

[image]

3. size of node_module directly affect the performance? How?

I want to optimize my nodejs application, how I should achieve that?

currently the node_module size is >800MB

Answer (score 0):

> 1 & 2: Does importing values affect performance?

Yes: every imported value (except types in the case that you're using TypeScript — because types aren't runtime values) has at least two costs:

1. A processor cost: each module is evaluated by the JavaScript runtime and its code is parsed and executed. Depending on the complexity of each module and how many modules are included in the entire module graph, this can certainly affect the startup time of your program in a non-trivial way. This is potentially compounded by CJS modules (which can use `require()` dynamically)  — or dynamic `import()` statements in ESM — because of lazily-evaluated imports.
2. A memory cost: each module that is included in the module graph likely declares and instantiates variables, functions, classes, etc. These values require memory to exist, and the sum of them is reflected as part of the memory cost of your program. If you import code from a module which creates an enormous, locally-scoped cache object that's needed by some part of the module's API — even if you never use that part of the API, the object will still exist and the memory it requires will still be used. You don't have control over this unless you're the module author, and that's one of many reasons why it's important to audit your dependencies and to profile the CPU and memory used by your programs in testing.

> 3. Does the size of the `node_modules` directory affect performance?

The locally-cached (downloaded) copy of packages within the `node_modules` directory are just files on disk: they require storage space on your storage device, but don't directly impact the performance of your program just by existing. That only becomes a factor as you actually import modules (or the modules that you directly import import other modules).

Comment: Does importing a single module in a directory instead of the entire directory of modules result in better performance & memory usage?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573867/does-importing-and-not-using-reduces-the-performance-nodejs/74574658?noredirect=1#comment136554847_74574658) @BrianTakita It depends on the module: which values are created by it, which modules it imports and which values are created in those, etc.